# Adding multiple shapes in d3

Tags: svg, d3.js

I would like to add different shapes depending on one of the properties in my json file. I found this approach by Mike:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/4EJDu1xOh8Y

The idea is great, I'm just not sure how to adapt it. I either want to add a circle or an svg:use element (with attr("xlink:href")). They both have (of course) different attributes. So how do I do that? What do I append? In the example, the attr("d") was also used, do I need that also? 
That's what I have so far but I'm not sure what to add where. 
I really appreciate your help!

```
var type = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(["Q", "C"])
  .range("circle","svg:use");

for(l=0;l<4;l++){

  currentsvg.selectAll("path")
    .data(queryArray[l])
    .enter()
    .append("svg:path")      
    .type(function(d,i) { 
        if (queryArray[l][i].name.substr(0,1) == "Q"){
         return type("Q");   
        }
        else if (queryArray[l][i].name.substr(0,1) == "C"){
          return type("C");   
        }
     });
}
```

Comment: Try to make a fiddle, then we could do something on it....

Comment: You could use a [superformula](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1021103).

Comment: Ok, I've started working on a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a4bn41m4/3/
I get an error on my console though but I don't know what this means: TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object.
return this.appendChild(name.apply(this, arguments));

Comment: Superformula looks good, too. I will try to understand that as well.

Comment: Ok, I tried a similar approach to superformula by appending a path and then setting the attr("d") to circle or rect: http://jsfiddle.net/a4bn41m4/5/
No more errors but I don't see anything, either.

Comment: This is not how `d` attributes work. You need to specify a path in SVG notation there.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I should have researched better, I didn't find a description in the d3 API so I just gave it a try. But does that mean that it's possible with the d attribute if I specify the SVG path correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a different solution without filtering that uses the path to draw the shapes. It doesn't use the "rect" or "circle" of svg but rather just uses the path to draw the shapes. Check out [here](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_path.asp) for more on paths. Note that the circle is two connecting arcs. It also classes each shape based on the data so you can have different colors, etc using CSS. [Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MattSL/qc01zc85/).

```
currentsvg.selectAll("path")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d",function(d,i){
        var path,
            s = i*50,
            r = 10,
            w = r*2;    
        if (data[i] == "Q"){
         path =  "M" + s + " " + s + " L" + s + " " + (s+w) +
             " L" + (s+w) + " " + (s+w) + " L" + (s+w) + " " + s + "Z" 
        }
        else if (data[i] == "C"){
         path =  "M" + s + " " + s + " m" + -r + ", 0 " +
             " a " + r + "," + r + " 0 1,0 " + r*2 + ",0" + 
             " a " + r + "," + r + " 0 1,0 "+ -r*2 + ",0"
        }
        return path;       
    })
    .attr("class", function(d){return d == "Q" ? "rec" : "circ";})
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is to filter the data how you want into separate data sets for each shape before you create shapes. Then you can create the shapes with that new data set.

```
var data = ["Q","Q","Q","C","C","Q","Q","C","Q","C"];

var circleSet = data.filter(function(d){return d === "Q";}),
    squareSet = data.filter(function(d){return d === "C";});
```

As Lars said, that is also not how the *d* attribute works. Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MattSL/sqgcvx3b/) of the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I know about filtering, I just didn't think about it because I wanted to preserve the order of the elements in the array and position them with the index. That's why I was interested in the other solution but I guess I will use filtering now. Does that mean it's not possible with the above approach?

Comment: Ok, I understand now what you are going for. I just posted another answer that is much closer to your example that uses the d of path.